# Lion specific features

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am developping a Mac application requiring Mac OS 10.6. However I am interested to add a Lion specific feature (fullscreen support).
What is the way to properly manage that (I am planning to use the Mac App Store):

- 2 different versions?
- a "special" version combining 2 version and using automatically the right one depending of the system?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Base SDK to Lion, but the Deployment Target to the oldest version you want to support, and the newer features are available via [weak linking](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/building-for-earlier-os-versions-in.html)